# Printing multiline strings using list of patterns

Tags: python

I am trying to create a Seven Segment Display using a list of patterns but my output is coming on new line but I want all digits on same line parallel in horizontal not in vertical shape.. Please help me!

[image]

**My code:**

```
SevenSeg = ["""###\n# #\n# #\n# #\n###""", """#\n#\n#""", """###\n  #\n###\n#\n###""", '###\n  #\n###\n  #\n###', '# #\n# #\n###\n  #\n  #', '###\n#\n###\n  #\n###', '###\n#\n###\n# #\n###', '###\n  #\n  #\n  #\n  #', '###\n# #\n###\n# #\n###', '###\n# #\n###\n  #\n###',  ]

def SevenSegment():
    desireNum = input("Enter a number you want to display on SEVEN SEGMENT DISPLAY: ")
    indexLst = list(desireNum)
    # print(indexLst)
    str = []
    display = ''
    for i in range(len(indexLst)):
        digit= int(indexLst[i])
        str.append(SevenSeg[digit])

    for i in range(len(str)):
        print(str[i])
    return None

print(SevenSegment())
```

**My output and desired output screenshots:**

[image]

Comment: Use print (str[i], end = "    ") for adding space after print statement instead of a new line. That should do the work I think.

Comment: No adding that wont work. because its printing char by char, not whole integer by interger

Comment: @Costa no that will make things worse

Answer (score 2):

Hi try the following code:

```
SevenSeg = ["""###\n# #\n# #\n# #\n###""", """ #\n #\n #\n #\n #""", """###\n  #\n###\n#\n###""", '###\n  #\n###\n  #\n###', '# #\n# #\n###\n  #\n  #', '###\n#\n###\n  #\n###', '###\n#\n###\n# #\n###', '###\n  #\n  #\n  #\n  #', '###\n# #\n###\n# #\n###', '###\n# #\n###\n  #\n###',  ]

def SevenSegment():
    desireNum = input("Enter a number you want to display on SEVEN SEGMENT DISPLAY: ")
    indexLst = list(desireNum)
    str = []
    for i in range(len(indexLst)):
      digit = int(indexLst[i])
      str.append(SevenSeg[digit])

    print(str)
    for j in range(0, 5):
      for i in range(len(str)):
        print(str[i].split("\n")[j], end="\t")
      print("")

SevenSegment()
```

Your previous code won't work because you print a full number structure on every for loop and doing it like this you can't never make it works. 
Instead you need, on each loop, to print the first line of every number you need to display on the same (and I do this with the outer `for on j` and with the `split on "\n"`). So I modified the structure of the number 1, because *every number need to have the same count of rows.*\

**EDIT**
Obviusly you need a `\t` at the end of each series of `'#'` for each number, so the `print` won't be with `end=" "` but with `end="\t"`. Thanks to @Shivam Bharadwaj for the advice. 
You can test it here: https://repl.it/repls/ReadyLastingDos

Comment: `print(str[i].split("\n")[j], end="\t\t")` will be good format